# Fix bad commit dates

Tags: svn, timestamp

I'm trying to import to phabricator a subversion repository and I'm found that there a lot of commits with wrong dates. This dates are set on the future, like 3905-05-22 . If there a few, I could be changing it by hand, but I found that there too many.

There is a way to do a massive change of time-stamps of svn commits, or a way that subversion self-correct these invalid dates ?

Note: I'm usually work over git, so I'm not a pro svn user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended writing a script to fix it :

```
#!/bin/bash
LAST_COMMIT=$(svn info svn://XXX/ | grep -i rev | tail -n1 | grep -o -E '[0-9]+')

echo "Ultimo commit ${LAST_COMMIT}"
for COMMIT in $(seq 12190 $LAST_COMMIT)
do
  FECHA_COM=$(svn propget svn:date --revprop -r $COMMIT svn://desarrollo01/)
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Error!"
    exit $?;
  fi
  if [ ${FECHA_COM:0:2} -gt "20" ]; then
    NFECHA_COM="20${FECHA_COM:2:${#FECHA_COM}}"
    echo "${COMMIT} : ${FECHA_COM} -> ${NFECHA_COM}"
    svn propset --revprop -r $COMMIT svn:date ${NFECHA_COM}  svn://XXX/ 
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
      echo "Error!"
      exit $?;
    fi
  fi                               
done;
```

Were 12190 is were begins the bad commits. At this moment, it has been fix around 2000 commits with this. It's taking some time to check the whole 50000 commits from our repo, but at least we will know that this has been fixed.

Comment: The scripts iterates every commit and gets his date. If it find that the two first digits of the year are greater that 20 (ie 3905), then replaces it by "20", restoring the wrong date to 2005. This fixed our issue, and now Phabricator and git svn can process the subversion repository correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to dump to a file, replace, and load it again:

- svn dump
- sed ....
- svn load